# System.CalloutException: Unable to tunnel through proxy (Winter '16 issue)

Tags: apex, callout, winter16

This morning I'm seeing sporadic failures across the board for our various integrations in production. When using `HTTPRequest` callouts, a `System.CalloutException` is being thrown with the following message:

`First error: IO Exception: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error"`

And less frequently: `First error: IO Exception: Connection reset`

This is popping up on webservice callouts that have been working without issue anywhere from a month to 2 years. We are not making any of these requests through a proxy. Some requests to an endpoint fail with this error, and I see several seconds later another request that succeeds. I have opened an urgent ticket with Salesforce, although they have yet to respond.

Are we running into some limit  with concurrent requests that I'm unaware of?

Update: Salesforce support says others are reporting this as well, and R&D is looking into the issue.

Update: This issue is now listed on https://trust.salesforce.com/trust/instances

Update: The Salesforce Technology Team has identified a fix for the issue causing intermittent errors with Single Sign-On logins and outbound HTTP calls. The fix is currently undergoing testing prior to deployment. Deployment will begin once the testing and validation is completed. Please check the status of trust.salesforce.com frequently for updates regarding this issue.

Final Update: The Salesforce Technology Team has resolved the performance degradation affecting multiple instances for the issue causing intermittent errors with Single Sign-On logins and outbound HTTP calls. The problem began at 13:00 UTC and was resolved by 21:38 UTC.

[image: trust.salesforce.com]

Comment: We're seeing this too for the first time. A 500 error indicates something went wrong on the Salesforce side. I'm glad to hear others are seeing this.

Comment: Can you check if there is some downtime on your instance http://trust.salesforce.com/trust/instances

Comment: Yep, that was the first thing I did. We're on NA18. Winter '16 release went live for us this past Saturday.

Comment: We are seeing this too.

Comment: Our org is facing this as well, but it's happening sporadically. In instances where users have the ability to resend web calls, we currently have them making multiple attempts until the request goes through. So if your situation permits users to resend the web calls, you may want to try that route until it's fixed.

Comment: I've been watching the logs and retrying a few things manually wherever possible. Unfortunately some of our callouts are so deep under the hood that in most cases our users wouldn't even be aware that there was a failure.

Comment: Seeing the same thing in a customer org on NA27. Last occurrence almost an hour ago so I'm hoping it is close to being fixed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what Salesforce told me:

"Unfortunately this a known issue currently going in Salesforce regarding HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error.

Our R&D team is aggressively working to resolve the issue asap . We will keep you updated on this."

Update:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please check this out issue due to winter 16 release, on few servers its already been fixed.

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008ZsoAAE